# Gematrias or Roshei Taivos for the year 5772

Tags: calendar, acronyms, gematria-numerology

Looking for Gematrios of phrases and/or Roshei Teivos that are appropiate for the year 5772 (by adding up to either 5772 or 772, which is the accepted numerical abbreviation for the year after conventionally leaving out the "thousands placeholder").

For example תהילים: לג. א.
- **ר**ננו **צ**דיקים **ב**יהוה **ל**ישרים **נ**אוה **ת**הלה
- the Roshei taivos of this verse = 772 - which is תשע"ב.

Comment: Title pages of books often include phrases of which occasional letters combine to the _gimatriya_ of the year. Do you want even that sort of thing?

Comment: Either phrases or Roshei Teivos.

Answer (score 7):

Well let's see here,

If you're looking for a backronym in Tanach it's pretty slim pickings inspiration-wise.

Ezekiel 7:20:

> וצבי עדיו לגאון שמהו וצלמי **ת**ועבתם **ש**קוציהם **ע**שו **ב**ו על כן נתתיו להם לנדה
>
> and statues of their awful, disgusting things they made ...

Isaiah 38:12-13:

> מיום עד-לילה **ת**שלימני.   **ש**ויתי **ע**ד-**ב**קר כארי
>
> I was a goner; I braced myself till morning.

I'm not finding any sofei teivos.

Moseying on over to the Babylonian Talmud, we do a bit better. In order of increasing inspiration (well according to me anyway):

Temurah 3a:

> **ת**עשה **ש**בתורה **ע**שה **ב**ו
>
> A "don't do" commandment, if [actively] done

*Okay! I'll try not to sin in 5772! What about working on my relationships with fellow man?*

Kiddushin 63a:

> **ת**ניא **ש**ב **ע**מי **ב**צוותא
>
> It was taught, "sit together with me."

Eruvin 48a:

> **ת**ימא **ש**נתנו **ע**ירובן **ב**אמצעית
>
> If you say they put their *eruv* in the middle

*Alright; how about some Torah study for the new year?*

Sanhedrin 44b:

> **ת**מידין **ש**נאמר **ע**תה **ב**אתי
>
> [Torah study is greater than] daily sacrifices, as it says [in Joshua], "now I came."

*And finally, now shouldn't I pay more attention to prayer this year?*

Megillah 17b:

> **ת**יקנו **ש**מונה **ע**שרה **ב**רכות
>
> [The sages] enacted [18 blessings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah)

---

If we go for Gematrias, Jeremiah 1:17 is a complete verse with Gematria 5772, and is pretty inspiring:

> ואתה תאזר מתניך וקמת ודברת אליהם את כל אשר אנכי אצוך אל תחת מפניהם פן אחתך לפניהם
>
> Now you shall gird your loins, get up and tell them what I command you; don't break with fear of them or I will break you with fear in front of them.

There's actually one more complete 5772 verse, but a bit more depressing:

> ויקשר קשר הושע בן אלה על פקח בן רמליהו ויכהו וימיתהו וימלך תחתיו בשנת עשרים ליותם בן עזיה

About one Jewish king who overthrew and killed another one. Woo-hoo. (This was in the "circling the drain" period for Israel's North Kingdom.)

There are plenty of Biblical phrases with gematria 5772, but often they're sentence fragments that leave you hanging; this one works pretty well on its own:

> כאשר שש על אבתיך כי תשמע בקול יהוה אלהיך לשמר מצותיו וחקתיו הכתובה בספר התורה

Comment: these are good! how did you find the pesukim by gematria?

Comment: @HodofHod, computer script operating on mechon-mamre's text; same as in similar problems.

Answer (score 6):

Various people always come up with phrases starting with "תהא שנת" whose initials are the standard alphabetic representation of the year's number (or a variant thereof when the standard is a bad word like תשמד). I suppose we can do so collectively here. I'm making this answer community wiki to collect such. Please add to the list.

תהא שנת...‏

- עבודת בוראנו
- עמלות בתורה
- ערָבה בעזָרה
- <del>עגבניות בסלט</del>

Comment: I like the salad. Note that neither *agvaniyot* nor *salat* are Biblical or classical Hebrew.

Answer (score 2):

ישמך אלקים **כאפרים וכמנשה** - בראשית: מח. כ.

כאפרים וכמנשה = 772

---

כי **ה' ברך** את עמו - דברי הימים ב: לא. י

26 x 222 = 5772

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice one:

תְּהִלִּים קלח:ב - אֶשְׁתַּחֲוֶה. אֶל הֵיכַל קָדְשְׁךָ **וְאוֹדֶה אֶת שְׁמֶךָ עַל חַסְדְּךָ וְעַל אֲמִתֶּךָ כִּי הִגְדַּלְתָּ עַל כָּל שִׁמְךָ אִמְרָתֶךָ בְּיוֹם. קָרָאתִי וַתַּעֲנֵנִי תַּרְהִבֵנִי בְנַפְשִׁי עֹז יוֹדוּךָ**. יְהוָה כָּל מַלְכֵי אָרֶץ כִּי שָׁמְעוּ אִמְרֵי פִיךָ

I built a site which calculated every possible gematria for Chumash and Tehillim in sequential order from one word to three pasukim.

Btw, it has no ads or pictures 
Its: http://www.secretorah.com

Avner

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure (despite your comment on the question) whether this is what you want, but many title pages of books include phrases of which certain letters are picked out to form the *gimatriya* of the year of publication. Along those lines, we can have

**תׄהׄ**י נ**שׄ**מתו צרור**הׄ בׄ**צרור הח**יׄיׄםׄ**

(with the תה...ש...הב...יים picked out).

(Not a good answer IMO, this is more to see whether Gershon Gold (the question's author) wants even this kind of thing, and also to point out how plentiful such will be. I mean you can do to many, many phrases what I did above to that one. But it is an answer, which is why I'm posting it as such.)

Comment: No. I am looking for either Gematrias of phrase or Pesukim or Roshei Taivos or Sofei Taivos. Not picking out letters unless they are evenly spaced.

Answer (score 0):

Gematria
2654: **לְמַעַן תִּזְכֹּר אֶת יוֹם צֵאתְךָ מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם כֹּל יְמֵי חַיֶּיךָ**
2654: הַמִּצְו‍ֹת וְהַמִּשְׁפָּטִים אֲשֶׁר צִוָּה יְהוָה בְּיַד מֹשֶׁה אֶל בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל
2654: לְבָבְךָ וּבְכָל נַפְשֶׁךָ. כִּי הַמִּצְוָה הַזֹּאת אֲשֶׁר אָנֹכִי מְצַוְּךָ הַיּוֹם לֹא נִפְלֵאת הִוא מִמְּךָ
2654: חַיֶּיךָ וְאֹרֶךְ יָמֶיךָ לָשֶׁבֶת עַל הָאֲדָמָה אֲשֶׁר נִשְׁבַּע יְהוָה לַאֲבֹתֶיךָ
2654: וְרֹב דָּגָן וְתִירֹשׁ. יַעַבְדוּךָ עַמִּים וישתחו לְךָ לְאֻמִּים הֱוֵה גְבִיר לְאַחֶיךָ
2654: אִישׁ אֶל אֲחֻזָּתוֹ וְאִישׁ אֶל מִשְׁפַּחְתּוֹ תָּשֻׁבוּ.
2654: סַבּוּנִי. כִדְבוֹרִים דֹּעֲכוּ כְּאֵשׁ קוֹצִים בְּשֵׁם יְהוָה כִּי אֲמִילַם דַּחֹה. דְחִיתַנִי לִנְפֹּל וַיהוָה עֲזָרָנִי
2654: אֶבֶן. מָאֲסוּ הַבּוֹנִים הָיְתָה לְרֹאשׁ פִּנָּה מֵאֵת. יְהוָה הָיְתָה זֹּאת
2654: יָבֹא עֶזְרִי עֶזְרִי. מֵעִם יְהוָה עֹשֵׂה שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ אַל. יִתֵּן לַמּוֹט רַגְלֶךָ
2654: כְּרַחֵם. אָב עַל בָּנִים רִחַם יְהוָה עַל יְרֵאָיו כִּי. הוּא יָדַע יִצְרֵנוּ זָכוּר כִּי עָפָר אֲנָחְנוּ וְחֶסֶד. יְהוָה מֵעוֹלָם וְעַד